# hover to animate css, hover out going back to normal

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, baseline

http://jsfiddle.net/n8mjtyz0/11/

I have simple animation with jquery and css.
When I hover I want texts around span to animate. 
When I hover out I want texts to be normal to original.

I seem to succeed in the first hover, but I cannot get the hover out part.

```js
$(".mapname").mouseover(function() {
  $(".baseup").animate({
    top: "-0.19em"
  }, function() {
    $(".baseup").anmiate({
      top: "0"
    });
  });
});
```

```css
.mapname {
  position: fixed;
  font-size: 1.3em;
  top: 10px;
  left: 20px;
}

.baseup {
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="mapname" id="click">
  G
  <span class="baseshow baseup">eograp</span> hi
  <span class="baseshow baseup">ca</span> l M
  <span class="baseshow baseup">ap</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Probably because of a typo ??? `$(".baseup").anmiate({` -- anmiate() is not a function... ;)

Comment: oh...god yes. I need glasses.

Comment: Yes, @LouysPatriceBessette nailed it. It is the typo in mouseout. Replace anmiate with animate.

Comment: For future reference you should use the developer console of the browser to watch for errors when JS code doesn't work as you expect it to. Press F12 to open it

Comment: And [`.mouseover()`](https://api.jquery.com/mouseover/) does not take two handlers... Use [`.hover()`](https://api.jquery.com/hover/).

Comment: Thanks everybody for tips!

Answer (score 1):

You have misspelled `animate` as `anminate`, change it like this, and it will work.

```
 function() {
    $(".baseup").animate({
    top: "0"
    });
  });
 });
```